# Trigger i:active when keydown on HTML page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm making a HTML page to control a RC Car. I want to be able to activate the "i:active" in CSS when keyboard arrows are down. The arrows in HTML:

```
<i class="left" onmousedown="venstreFunc()" ></i>
<i class="up"  onmousedown="fremoverFunc()" ></i>
<i class="right" onmousedown="hoyreFunc()"  ></i>
<i class="down" onmousedown="bakoverFunc()" ></i>
```

I can drive the RC car with both mousedown and the keydown events in my JavaScript, but i want to be able to see the orange border when i push down the keyboard arrows

How can I implement the keyboard arrow events to give the same orange border on the arrows as when I click/hold down on them?

```js
document.onkeydown = checkKey;
function checkKey(e) {
    e = e || window.event;

    if (e.keyCode == '38') {
       connection.send("1");
    }
    else if (e.keyCode == '40') {
        connection.send("4");
    }
    else if (e.keyCode == '37') {
       connection.send("2");
    }
    else if (e.keyCode == '39') {
       connection.send("3");
    }
}
```

```css
i {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-width: 0 20px 20px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 24px;
  cursor:pointer;
  position: absolute;
  outline:none;
}

i:active {
 border-right: solid orange;
    border-bottom: solid orange;
    border-width: 0 13px 13px 0;
}

.up {
    transform: rotate(-135deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-135deg);
     margin: 50px 0  0 200px;
}

.right {
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    margin: 150px 0 0 300px;
}

.down {
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
     margin: 240px 0 0 200px;
}

.left {
    transform: rotate(135deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(135deg);
    margin:150px 0 0 100px;
}
```

```html
<i class="left" onmousedown="venstreFunc()" ></i>
<i class="up"  onmousedown="fremoverFunc()" ></i>
<i class="right" onmousedown="hoyreFunc()"  ></i>
<i class="down" onmousedown="bakoverFunc()" ></i>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would sugest is to manage `active` class instead of state on keyboard events. So add CSS rule for `active` class:

```
i:active,
i.active {
    border-right: solid orange;
    border-bottom: solid orange;
    border-width: 0 13px 13px 0;
}
```

And then add and remove this class on `onkeydown` and `onkeyup` events.

Example on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/34dqhev9/4/).

Answer (score 0):

element.classList.add("mystyle"); ? (with .mystyle{color:orange;})

this before your connection.send()

i don't know if it works

Answer (score 0):

***ABOUT CSS CODE:***

*how @Vaidas say's add -> i.active next to i:active.*

***JS CODE:***

I just implement the left arrow.

```
 document.addEventListener("keydown",function(event){
        paintArrow(event.key);
    });
    //
    var iElements = document.querySelectorAll('i');
    function paintArrow (keypressed) {
        [].forEach.call(iElements, function(iElement) {
        let className = iElement.className;
       if ( className === 'left' && keypressed === 'ArrowLeft' ) {
            iElement.className+= ' active';
          setTimeout(function(){iElement.className='left';},24)
       }
    });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<script>
    document.onkeydown = checkKey;
    function checkKey(e) {
        e = e || window.event;
        if (e.keyCode > 36 && e.keyCode < 41) {
            $('i').removeClass('active');
            if (e.keyCode == '38') {
                $('.up').addClass('active');
            }
            else if (e.keyCode == '40') {
                $('.down').addClass('active');
            }
            else if (e.keyCode == '37') {
                $('.left').addClass('active');
            }
            else if (e.keyCode == '39') {
                $('.right').addClass('active');
            }
        }            
    }
    </script>

<style>
        i.active {
            border-right: solid orange;
            border-bottom: solid orange;
            border-width: 0 13px 13px 0;
        }
</style>
```